# how to submit form name and submit button name in ajax form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I am looking for some concise solution in which i am able to send form name and submit button name with form input fields. I have tries form.serializeArray() method but I am getting only input fields name inside post. then how can I send complete form data with form name and submit button name in just one line code

```
 <form id="formid" name="formName" class="formClass" action="service.php" method="POST" >
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" />
        <input type="Submit" id="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT" name="submit"/>

    </form>

    $( "#formid" ).submit(function( event ) {
    //var array = $(this).serializeArray() ;  //  Didn't send Form name and submit button
    // var data2 = new FormData($( "#formid" )[0]); // I have also tried this



      $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url : $(this).attr('action') , 
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data:  formData,
        complete:function(httpResponse, status) {
        var response = httpResponse.responseText;       
        alert(response);

        }
      });


    event.preventDefault();
```

});

I want to send Form name and Submit Button Name in ajax just like it works when page reloaded after submission of form.

For more I have tried  [MALSUP](http://jquery.malsup.com/) in which I am able to send form name and submit button name in the POST data. So what would be alternative way to do this in Jquery AJAX

Comment: Could you please include an example of relevant code, so we can better understand the problem? See the [posting guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for information about asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got my answer. Even when the page reloads after submitting the form, the form name does not go with the form data. Only the all the input elements with submit button name is sent into the form data. Even the input type="button" element name does not go into form data.

But with AJAX form submission when we use ('form').serialize() method OR ('form').serailizeArray() method all the form elements value with their names are serialize but SUBMIT Button value DOES NOT SERIALIZE with this. But I found a solution to send submit button NAME and VALUE with minimum lines of code.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
     for (var i = 0; i < $(this)[0].length; i++) {
        formdata.append($(this)[0][i].name, $(this)[0][i].value);
    }
```

the above code will make the array of all elements including with submit button NAME and VALUE. The benefit of this is we can check for the submit button name at SERVER SIDE and can perform the valuable operations on the basis of only one condition.

Comment: If there are multiple submit buttons with different values, does this submit all the submit button values, regardless of which is clicked? It might make more sense to just have a hidden input if the server is expecting to always get a "SUBMIT" field with a value of "submit".